# Function chdir() is behaving weirdly

Tags: c, linux, shell, chdir

```
int cmd_cd(char* argv[]) {
  if(argv[1] == NULL || strncmp("~", argv[1], 1) == 0){
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    if(argv[1] == NULL || strlen(argv[1]) == 1){
      argv[1] = pw->pw_dir;
    }
    else{
      char path[strlen(pw->pw_dir) + strlen(arg[1])];
      strcpy(path, pw->pw_dir);
      argv[1] = &argv[1][1];
      strcat(path, argv[1]);
      argv[1] = path;
    }
  }

  if(chdir(argv[1])<0) {
    printf("Not a valid path\n");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Above is a snippet of code in which I am trying to make a toy linux shell. But the code above is buggy as when I type

> $  cd ~/code

it executes as expected, but in the below case its says "Not a valid path". And I am unable to figure out why.

> $  cd ~/code/[name_of_some_valid_directory]

Comment: With any path under there or just with some? What value is set in `errno` when it fails?

Comment: if 'argv' has the usual meaning, then it is located in readonly memory so the result of running this would be a seg fault event.

Comment: `strncmp("~", argv[1], 1) == 0)` would be simpler, faster and more readable if you wrote it as: `argv[1][0] == '~'`

Comment: the question is about a runtime problem.  Therefore, the code must cleanly compile, be executable, and show the problem.  The posted code does not meet any of that criteria

Comment: @user3629249: `main()`'s `char**` "string"s aren't `const` or read-only.

Comment: @user3629249: That is not correct. `argv` and the strings it points to are mutable. (On the systems I know, they live on the stack. But this is not guaranteed.)

Comment: This isn't the source of your bug, but just a semantic correctness issue: `~` expands to `$HOME`, not the passwd db home directory for the current user. `~username` on the other hand expands to *username*'s home directory from the passwd db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`path` is deleted on exiting the block it is defined.

Try this:

```
int cmd_cd(char* argv[]) {
  char *path = NULL;
  if(argv[1] == NULL || strncmp("~", argv[1], 1) == 0){
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    if(argv[1] == NULL || strlen(argv[1]) == 1){
      argv[1] = pw->pw_dir;
    }
    else{
      path = malloc(strlen(pw->pw_dir) + strlen(arg[1]));
      if (path == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return -1;
      }
      strcpy(path, pw->pw_dir);
      argv[1] = &argv[1][1];
      strcat(path, argv[1]);
      argv[1] = path;
    }
  }

  if(chdir(argv[1])<0) {
    printf("Not a valid path\n");
    if (path != NULL) free(path);
    return -1;
  }
  if (path != NULL) free(path);
  return 0;
}
```

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` to the head of your code if needed to use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: This test `if (path != NULL)` is not needed as calling `free()` on a null-pointer is well defined.

Answer (score 2):

The value assigned here

```
argv[1] = path;
```

isn't valid any more here

```
if(chdir(argv[1])<0) {
```

as the scope (`{...}`) in which `path` is defined, is valid has already been left, so `argv[1]` is pointing to invalid memory.

The call to `chdir()` then accesses this invalid memory, which in turn provokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour, anything can happen from then on.